# Is the coin rigged?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Me and my friends did argue on this scenario about probability.

Suppose I toss a coin, with a normal head-tail coin (hence we suppose a priori the coin is not rigged [but we do know really know]), for $50$ times, and every time I obtain $H$.
What is the probability to get another head in the $51$-th toss?

For what concern the probability, I would say that there is always a $50/50$ chance, but someone pointed out that if we get fifty heads on a row, then the coin "must be" rigged.

Is this true? I mean what evidence coul make me really infer that the coin could be rigged?
Sure, the probability to obtain fifty heads in a row is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{50}$ hence incredibly small. Yet not zero.

Someone else pointed out that we must pay attention between the "classical probabilty and the statistical probabilty" which I did not understand really clearly (is there such a difference, such a thing?)

So in my opinion there is no real evidence for the coin to be rigged. The event is completely possible, just very improbable.

What is the "solution" to this conundrum?

Comment: Good question.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession for a glimpse at the iceberg's top.

Comment: If there is a non-zero probability the coin is rigged, then it depends on that probability. It is not probability $1$ that the coin is fair. That said, no amount of heads in a row can **prove** the coin is rigged. But it makes the conditional probability that it is rigged increase.

Comment: @kimchilover That is an awesome page! How to deal with that though? In the first case, if we assume to know that both failure and success are possible, then according to my question and that article, I would get

$$P(X_{51} = 1 = \text{head} | X_1 + \ldots + X_{50} = 50) = \frac{51}{52}$$

Yet if we know know from the beginnint that both success and failure are possible, then I would get $P = 1$. Though in this last case, it says it's not valid for $s = 0$ or $s = 1$ (that is: have gotten always head or tail)...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you elaborate more on "it makes the conditional probability that it is rigged increase"? Also what you think about my last comment, in relation to Wikipedia article?

Comment: What does the gobbledegook "[but we do know really know]" mean?

Comment: @DanAsimov It means that we assume we have a fair coin, but we do not really know a priori. It might be a fair coin or it mightn't. No information is given. Hence the perplexity in obtaining $50$ heads in a row, which is possible but very improbable. Yet possible, hence the coin could be fair, or not. And from here the rest of the problem.

Comment: "So in my opinion there is no real evidence for the coin to be rigged. The event is completely possible, just very improbable."   What event are you referring to?  And how can you *not* consider 50 heads in a row to be anything other than evidence that the coin is not a fair coin? (Note that I said "evidence", not "proof".)

Comment: If the probability is $p$ that the coin is rigged to always come up heads, then the probability that the coin is fair is at most and the probability we get $n$ heads in a row is at most $p+\left(\frac{1-p}2\right)^n<p+\frac1{2^n},$ so the conditional probability that the coin is rigged given we got $n$ heads in a row is at least $$\frac{p}{p+\frac{1}{2^n}},$$ which converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty.$ So for $n=50,$ you'd have a probability of the coin being rigged being greater than $$\frac{2^{50}p}{^{50}p+1}=1-\frac{1}{2^{50}p+1}$$

Comment: The question does not involve any probability *p* of the coin's being not a fair coin.

Comment: @DanAsimov Not explicitly, but it doesn't assume that the coin is fair, either. I am giving the simplest model, but we can get other more complicated continuous models, which will take more work. And, of course, if we assume the coin is fair, there is a $p,$ namely $p=0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good morning again! I was thinking about this: can we run a $\chi$-squared test on this problem? It would imply the coin is surely rigged, isn't it? Or can't we?